# migration extjs code from 3.4 to 4.2

Tags: extjs4.2

I have this code which work correctly in extjs 3.4

I want to migrate this code in order to be worked in extjs 4.2

```
  Ext.apply(this.menu.picker,  {
            minDate : this.minValue,
            maxDate : this.maxValue,
            disabledDatesRE : this.disabledDatesRE,
            disabledDatesText : this.disabledDatesText,
            disabledDays : this.disabledDays,
            disabledDaysText : this.disabledDaysText,
            format : this.format,
            showToday : this.showToday,
            startDay: this.startDay,
            minText : String.format(this.minText, this.formatDate(this.minValue)),
            maxText : String.format(this.maxText, this.formatDate(this.maxValue)),
            field: this
        });
```

when I test this code I find error in this line :

```
  minText : String.format(this.minText, this.formatDate(this.minValue)),
                maxText : String.format(this.maxText, this.formatDate(this.maxValue)),
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Object function String() { [native code] } has no method 'format'**

Answer (score 1):

franco, have you tried

```
    Ext.String.format(params)
```

instead of String.format() ?

Best
Rajinder